# Run python script when internet connection becomes available on Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, bash, networking, nvidia-jetson-nano

I need to setup a Jetson Nano device so that a Python script is launched everytime an Internet connection is available.

So, referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection), I did the following:

- I created the 'run_when_connection_available' script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# create a dummy folder to check script execution
mkdir /home /user_name/dummy_folder_00

# kill previous instances of the system
pkill python3

# move to folder with python script and launch it
cd /home/user_name/projects/folder
/usr/bin/python3 launcher.py --arg01 --arg02 ...

# create another dummy folder to check script execution
mkdir /home /user_name/dummy_folder_01
```

- I made this script executable and I copied it to /etc/network/if-up.d

Now, everytime I plug the ethernet cable out and in again, I can see the dummy folders are created in /home/user_name, but the python script isn't launched (at least, it doesn't appear in the system monitor). I tried running the command in the script from the terminal, and everything works fine, the python program starts as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess it was a matter of permissions, I solved it by running everything as user_name, so I modified the script as

```
sudo -user user_name /usr/bin/python3 launcher.py --arg01 --arg02 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure out something *similar* to you, but not quite the same..

This solution got my script python script running **upon internet connection**, I can check the logs and everything is working fine:

[Raspbian - Running A Script After An Internet Connection Is Established](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78991/running-a-script-after-an-internet-connection-is-established#answer-79033)

However, my script uses notify-send to send notifications to my window manager which I can't seem to get working with systemd - the script works when run inside of the user space so I assume it's something to do with systemd and Xorg. Hopefully that shouldn't be a problem for you, I hope this solves your issue.

You shouldn't need a bash script in the middle, I got systemd service to run my python script with `chmod u+x <file>.py` and putting `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top of the python file so that it's executable directly under the .service file like so:

`ExecStart=/path/to/file/file.py`